# É possível usar o MariaDB para clusterização?

Tags: mariadb, clusterização

Estou estudando a respeito de clusterização de banco de dados SQL, e para me aprofundar mais pretendo executar alguns testes práticos com um SGBD, e escolhi o MariaDB para isto.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar o MariaDB para clusterização e qual seria a versão dele para esta finalidade?

Comment: Acredito que os estudos voltados para MySQL vão contemplar o MariaDB. Ou seja, provavelmente há muito mais infos sobre MySQL, então, pode estudar com o termo antigo e testar no novo para confirmar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas opções, mas a que conheço e já usei pessoalmente (e recomendaria) é o [MariaDB Galera Cluster](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/), um cluster [multi-master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication) para mariadb. Um cluster multi-master é onde qualquer nó tem autoridade para ler/escrever, todos são "masters", diferente de um master-slave onde apenas 1 "master" escreve e os "slaves" só tem leitura.

O mundo de clusterização de bancos de dados é cheio de abacaxis, se você quiser dar uma aprofundada recomendo ler [essa análise técnica do mariadb galera](https://aphyr.com/posts/327-jepsen-mariadb-galera-cluster).  uma leitura bem pesada, mas não é necessário entender tudo para pegar a ideia geral, e quando se está escolhendo uma database nada melhor que ver os pontos fracos dela.